# DbFunction.DiffMinutes { 'System.NotSupportedException' }

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, notsupportedexception, dbfunctions

I want write this code
this part of my code

```cs
    var today = DateTime.Now;
    var todayString = today.ToShortDateString();
    List<FB> fBList = _context.FBs.ToList();
    fBList = fBList.Where(x => DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(x.FB_CDate, x.FB_LTDate) > 20 ).ToList();
```

and this part return me this

```
    'DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(x.FB_CDate, x.FB_LTDate) > 20' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
```

Comment: are x.FB_CDate, x.FB_LTDate, both are datetime?

Comment: yes both of them are datetime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DbFunctions provides CLR methods that get translated to **database functions** when used in LINQ to Entities queries.
When you call `ToList()`,data is loaded into memory and DbFunctions causes an error. You need to change your code as follows:

```
 var today = DateTime.Now;
            var todayString = today.ToShortDateString();
            List<FB> fBList = _context.FBs.Where(x => DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(x.FB_CDate, x.FB_LTDate) > 20).ToList();
```

Comment: Delete the fourth line and change the third line  to `List<FB> fBList = _context.FBs.Where(x => DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(x.FB_CDate, x.FB_LTDate) > 20).ToList();`